# UI doesn't fill in iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, storyboard, iphone-6-plus

I'm working on an iOS app and realize the ui is not auto stretch to fit the screen when it's running in iPhone 6 plus.
So the UI is on the right left, and there are a lot of white space in the bottom and right.

If I set the width of a view to beyond 320 (ex. 400), then the view be wider than 320.

How could I make my views auto stretch to fill the screen?

I have a few other apps, and they works perfectly fine in iPhone 6 plus.

I couldn't figure out what make this app's ui not auto stretching.
The only difference I could think of it this one is create after the official xcode 6 is released, the others were created in xcode 6 beta version

Thanks!

Comment: How are you laying out your views? Autolayout? Programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start using auto-layouts. Start from here: [Auto layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Hi, I am facing UI related issue on 6s and 6s plus. I have designed the page by writing code instead of drag-drop. How can we get UI designs good for both 6s and 6s plus models?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you enabled native resolution for iPhone 6 Plus. If you delete "launch screen file" you can individually control which screen size will be supported as native resolution by adding related size of launch images.

[image]

[image]

[image]