# Xamarin iOS iPhone 6 Plus Not Filling Entire Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a default existing project in `Xamarin.Forms` version `1.2.3` and I have the same issue as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940860/ui-doesnt-fill-in-iphone-6-plus) hinting that `auto-layouts` should be used.

When I start the `iPhone 6 Plus` app, there is about 1cm black bar at the top and bottom of the page, with even the task notification bar at the top moved to the smaller size screen displayed when launching.

Its probably a one liner change but what and where does this need to be done?

I'm rather surprised this is not in the default template already however.

Comment: you have to see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861458/ios-how-to-fit-with-to-parent-view-use-autolayout/27861538#27861538